# Try to set timeout after success - angularjs

Tags: angularjs, timeout

i have modal box. I want submit form, show success message, and after 3 sec, close modal box. Here is my ctrl

```
            $http.post(serviceBase + 'aaaa', data, config)
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.PostDataResponse = data;
                    $scope.messages = ['Success'];

                }, startTimer())
                .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
                    var messages = [];
                    angular.forEach(data.errors, function (value, key) {
                        $scope.ResponseDetails = "Data: " + data +
                                "<hr />status: " + status +
                                "<hr />headers: " + header +
                                "<hr />config: " + config;
                        messages.push('Error! ' + key + ' is not correct');

                    });
                    $scope.messages = messages;
                });
                // expose dependencies on this


};
var startTimer = function () {
    var timer = $timeout(function () {
        $timeout.cancel(timer);
        $location.path('/klupe');
              }, 3000);

};
```

But timer not working, if i console.log $location.path, it's ok, but function startTimer() is not calling. Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the function call inside the success block, not as a second paramter

Comment: thnx, but still the same. I got success message, but timer is not started, not redirect me

Comment: Try removing cancel timer, `$timeout.cancel(timer);` this should ideally prevent the task from running

Comment: thanke you this working, and i also change $location.path to $state.go. But now i have another problem. How to close modal box with this timer? here is from my template <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$dimiss()" data-dismiss="modal"></button>

Comment: I dont get your requirement

Comment: Call the dismiss function before the path change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117690/discussion-between-arter-and-shintu-joseph).

Comment: var startTimer = function () {
        var timer = $timeout(function () {
            dismiss();
            $state.go('korisnici');
                  }, 3000);
        
    };   like this??